# Burn cd with cdfs format and open session

Tags: windows-7, audio, compact-disc, burning

I want to burn a cd in CDFS format from a Windows 7 computer. I might be wrong but as far as I could tell using the standard burn wizard in Win7 you can burn either in UDF or in CDFS format. I intend to use the CD in a car CD player which as far as I can tell only plays CDFS (I've tried both UDF and CDFS and it only played the CDFS).

My question is: is there any way I can burn a CD in CDFS format and still be able to add tracks to it later on? I believe this is called "not closing the session on the CD" or something like that.

The interesting part is that I have another CD (in CDFS format) which I burnt a couple of months ago with some video files on it. I tried adding a track to the CD whith the CD being in CDFS format and the CD player played the track without any problems. So that CD is in CDFS format and it has some video files on it and an MP3 file and I can still add other music.

That's pretty much the behaviour I want from my CD (actually I only want audio files but I want to be able to add new songs later on without having to re-burn  the entire CD). However so far I've been unable to replicate that scenario with another CD.

Any advice on how to do that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your disk player supports multi-session disks. Some players do not such disks at all, others can only read first session. To be safe, experiment with an erasable disk (CD-RW) first.

[CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) (free) should be able to burn leaving session open

Upon pressing `Burn` button (of a `data disk`) it should ask if you want to close the disk - choose to `Leave disk open`.

To add files to existing open disk, insert the disk, wait a 5-10 seconds, select the option to create new `data disk` and then select `continue disc`.

[This manual page](https://cdburnerxp.se/help/Data/compiledata) contains detailed instructions if you need them.

Comment: I bought 5 RW CDs because because I had previously used CD-Rs which didn't work in the car. Since I was able to play that CD with both the audio and video on it (which was not closed), doesn't this mean that the player can work with open sessions?

Comment: I don't know. Just try it with an RW. (be sure to actually record at least two sessions). You can always erase it if it doesn't. Most players I've seen only read 1st session and ignore anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I used the software you sugested and it worked fine.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, I suggest you `accept` it - that will mark your question as resolved to other people. Thanks.